# how to create object of partial class in c#.net?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, partial-classes

What exactly is the partial class in c#.net?

```
create button
{
 call constorctor

}
```

To create object of partial class in c#.net while using windows form application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating partial class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007756/creating-partial-class-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Follow below link for partial class definition,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods

You can create object of partial class as like any other class object .
e.g. classname obj = new classname();